How to do daily and Hourly task in django
I use Django 4.2.11 and I try to run a task hourly (or multiple task).
I found django-background-tasks and Django-Q but it all seem that they are old.
I also seen that Celery can do that but it's not integrated in Django.
is Celery a good way ?

You have a few options depending on your setup, if you're wanting something more simple locally you can use Crontab and it's quite straight forward to implement
https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/
Celery requires a fair bit more setup but is a good option for this along with anything else you would want to offload to a queue.
It's not just for CRON and could provide you with some great options as you potentially scale a project.
